# Linphone compilation error when compiling with x264 in v3.2

Tags: android

I have successfully compiled Linphone source code without x264 encoder.But when i add x264 encoder(i.e. ./prepare.py -DENABLE_X264=YES -DENABLE_NON_FREE_CODECS=YES).It gives me error in make step.I think problem is in configuration file of x264.I m using ndk-r12b and all pre requisites are installed. I shall be grateful.

make[3]: Entering directory `/home/usman/Downloads/linphone-android/WORK/android-armv7/cmake'
    [ 19%] Creating directories for 'EP_x264'
    [ 19%] No download step for 'EP_x264'
    [ 20%] No patch step for 'EP_x264'
    [ 20%] No update step for 'EP_x264'
    [ 20%] Performing configure step for 'EP_x264'
    No working C compiler found.
    make[3]: *** [/home/usman/Downloads/linphone-android/WORK/android-armv7/Stamp/EP_x264/EP_x264-configure] Error 1
    make[3]: Leaving directory`/home/usman/Downloads/linphone-android/WORK/android-armv7/cmake'
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/EP_x264.dir/all] Error 2
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/usman/Downloads/linphone-android/WORK/android-armv7/cmake'
    make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
        make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/usman/Downloads/linphone-android/WORK/android-armv7/cmake'
        make: *** [armv7-build] Error 2

Comment: I have successfully compiled 3.1.1.x branch of linphone with x264 codec with same condition.there is some problem inside v3.2 when using with x264 codec.thanks

Comment: Any help regarding compiling x264 codec with latest linphone-android source code